# Can I use SDWebImage with POST requests?

Tags: caching, post, afnetworking, sdwebimage

Here is my case.

I'm making an app which download a lot of images from a server. I'm using AFNeworking and everything is ok except image caching. It turns that the image server headers must have the cache-control set as 'private' for security reasons (don't ask me why) and therefore, the NSURLCache used by AFNetworking is useless.

Now, caching the images is essential in this app so I've been looking for a replacement and I found SDWebImage that seems to do exactly what I need. BUT, I wonder how can I use it to download images since I am getting everything through a POST url request, so the baseURL that I must provide to the method will almost always be the same, changing just the params I send as POST message.

Will SDWebImage hash every image independently or it will just use the url provided as key?.

I don't care if I'm not able to use the UIImage category but I really need some way to cache my images. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hadn't realize that you can use any string as key name the cached image. I'm using the params dictionary description encoded with base64 to get an unique string for each request and just checking if it exists in cache prior to download. It seems to work. Not as convenient as UIImage category but it make its work well.

Hope this helps someone.